# Dynamic SQL Statement Creation - Scala

Tags: sql, scala, pivot

I have a file with following values

```
matchId                                 Id
2e0c6c42-68ac-43e0-b130-1b986f61a462    segA
2e0c6c42-68ac-43e0-b130-1b986f61a463    segB
2e0c6c42-68ac-43e0-b130-1b986f61a463    segC
2e0c6c42-68ac-43e0-b130-1b986f61a463    segA
```

I want pivoted result like below

```
matchid                                    segA segB segC
2e0c6c42-68ac-43e0-b130-1b986f61a463       1    1    1
2e0c6c42-68ac-43e0-b130-1b986f61a462       1    0    0
```

This means some id is present in SegA and some in all segments (should be denoted as binary 1's and 0's)

Since number of segments can vary I want SQL statement to be generated dynamically using Scala as below (it should scale up or down as per number of segments e.g. today i have 10 seg tomorrow it can be 5 and so on.)
From SQL (AWS Redshift DB) perspective I can generate below query if I know number of segments already but this can get complicated as number of segment increase.

```
CREATE TABLE pivotedsegments distkey(match_id) AS (
SELECT match_id,
MAX(CASE WHEN segment='Seg1' then 1 else 0 end) Seg1,
MAX(CASE WHEN segment='Seg2' then 1 else 0 end) Seg2,
MAX(CASE WHEN segment='Seg3' then 1 else 0 end) Seg3,
MAX(CASE WHEN segment='Seg4' then 1 else 0 end) Seg4,
MAX(CASE WHEN segment='Seg5' then 1 else 0 end) Seg5,
MAX(CASE WHEN segment='Seg6' then 1 else 0 end) Seg6,
MAX(CASE WHEN segment='Seg7' then 1 else 0 end) Seg7,
MAX(CASE WHEN segment='Seg8' then 1 else 0 end) Seg8,
MAX(CASE WHEN segment='Seg9' then 1 else 0 end) Seg9,
MAX(CASE WHEN segment='Seg10' then 1 else 0 end) Seg10,
MAX(CASE WHEN segment='Seg11' then 1 else 0 end) Seg11,
.
.
.
.
From some-table group by matchid;
```

So I want to design an scala API that can read such file and convert result in pivoted manner.

Please suggest.

Comment: It's not clear what are you having problem with. Please provide the code you have so far.

Comment: I'm not sure how can I generate such Case statements dynamically in Scala. I'll edit my question to be more clear

Comment: if its dymanic, then what is it based on? what's the logic behind the dynamic generation?

Comment: updated question. let me know if it's clear

Comment: Hi @AlekseyIzmailov Did you get chance to look my problem statement?